# Duplicate functions results in Modal header

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am calling two separate functions in header and body of Modal. Functions are calling based upon ID of product that is coming from ajax. Both functions are defined in Cart_code.php.

Now the issue is the function that should display in body is also displaying in in the header of modal also.
I want to display both functions separately in their relevant portions like header and body.

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Cart.php",
                data: {"ID":id},
                success: function(result){
                    $('#ajaxResult').html(result);

                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Cart.php

```
include('includes/Cart_code.php');

    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['ID'])) {
        $cart_class = new cart_class($_POST['ID']);
        $cart_class->cart_head_info_print();
        $cart_class->cart_body_info_print();
        exit();
       }
    ?>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
          <img src="" class="showPic">
            <div id="ajaxResult">
            <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">

              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
              <!---HERE HEADER DATA WILL BE DISPLAY---->

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                <!---HERE BODY DATA WILL BE DISPLAY---->
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Then you should try with two ajax call . Or you can do one thing create model content over Cart.php file and display over $('.modal-header').html(result);

Comment: @DivyeshPatoriya
But is that really a nice approach?
And if i wanna go with your suggestion then how should i write php code for handling request for it?

Comment: I would replace all your HTML from `<div class="modal-header"...` to the end div of `<div class="modal-body"...` by something like  `<div id="ajaxResult"></div>`. In your `cart.php` manage to create both sections and buttons.

Comment: I'm suggesting a principle. You want a result from `cart.php` splitted in two. Why not have a unique result that includes your two buttons ? hey!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette

If you would replace Modal html then how Modal would be displayed?

Comment: Just replace the tags... In order to provide a destination for the ajax result.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette
You mean to say that i should wrap the both divs in parent div with id= 'ajaxResult'?
Is that you are saying?

Comment: Ok.. I just saw something... Is your cart.php calling it-self with the javascript ?

Comment: Yes.. Your last question is yes.

Comment: Sounds like you call me to update me... No good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.
Basic principle here.
*--THIS IS A COMMON MISUNDERTANDING OF THE AJAX USAGE--*.

Normally, you should have a page with a script that calls **another page** to update a section based on user input.

So create your main page.

Then, based on whatever input, call another script to update a section of this main page.

You should call a script to produce a small part of the page.
This «result» will end in a `div` of your main page.

Ajax power is to update a section of a page without reloading the page completely.

This image is in french... But didn't find anything like this in english (!)

[image]

1- Javascript action (user input)
2- Ajax request
3- Server-side execution
4- Result (ajax success)
5- Element in main page updated with result.

---

Consider the blue «navigateur» square to be the web page (x.php) initialy loaded from the server.

Then, on client-side (blue side)... Triggered or not by user action, jQuery or JavaScript calls a page to the server (green side -> y.php) to update a specific element (usually a `div`) of the page.

It's the same page user has in front of his eyes for a long time ago (can be only a couple seconds!) and wich is already fully loaded with script libraries and css rules.

The «result» should only provide new HTML (and additional js script if needed) to fill the main page destination element targeted by Ajax «success» callback... Wich is only A PART of the original page that has not reloaded or changed.

Comment: By sending request within the same page, i have solved my problem only by adding parent div according to your last suggested solution.
Anyways, God bless you !

Comment: .Hey!
There sis a little issue, Now functions are working fine but the css of Modal is distorted, All Modal has changed to white color.
What's this?

Comment: i have given green color to header but after applying your solution the green color and default margin of Modal has disapeeared

Comment: Did you split the MAIN page from the SECTIONS called via ajax? Or you still call myself to update myself?

Comment: My script is on the same file, on moving it to another page, i am facing some errors.

Comment: No good. with `$('#ajaxResult').html(result);` in your ajax success... You're telling the browser to REPLACE all what's in between `<div id="ajaxResult">` and its `</div>` with the RESULTING html produced by the called PHP. If you still call the page where the ajax  call is.. You're in the woods.

Comment: Means i would make separate php file to handle ajax response?

Comment: An ajax call to a page is a call to a complete page wich will land in a specific div of an existing page. That's the trick.

Comment: By separating the main page from script, i am still facing the same issue of css.